# Não consigo criar tabela ao rodar meu projeto no Flyway

Tags: java, spring

Escrevi em SQL minha tabela no arquivo e estou utilizando o flyway, já criei a classe tudo certinho mas quando vou subir o projeto não cria a tabela escrita e nem apresenta algum erro.

OBS: Eu até já deletei todas tabelas e quando eu vou rodar o projeto o Spring cria as tabelas com seu inserts menos essa tabela lancamentos.

```
CREATE TABLE lancamento (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descricao VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    data_vencimento DATE NOT NULL,
    data_pagamento DATE,
    valor DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    observacao VARCHAR(100),
    tipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_categoria BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_pessoa BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_categoria) REFERENCES categoria(codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_pessoa) REFERENCES pessoa(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Salário mensal', '2017-06-10', null, 6500.00, 'Distribuição de lucros', 'RECEITA', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Bahamas', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-10', 100.32, null, 'DESPESA', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Top Club', '2017-06-10', null, 120, null, 'RECEITA', 3, 3);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('CEMIG', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-10', 110.44, 'Geração', 'RECEITA', 3, 4);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('DMAE', '2017-06-10', null, 200.30, null, 'DESPESA', 3, 5);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Extra', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', 1010.32, null, 'RECEITA', 4, 6);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Bahamas', '2017-06-10', null, 500, null, 'RECEITA', 1, 7);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Top Club', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-10', 400.32, null, 'DESPESA', 4, 8);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Despachante', '2017-06-10', null, 123.64, 'Multas', 'DESPESA', 3, 9);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Pneus', '2017-04-10', '2017-04-10', 665.33, null, 'RECEITA', 5, 10);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Café', '2017-06-10', null, 8.32, null, 'DESPESA', 1, 5);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Eletrônicos', '2017-04-10', '2017-04-10', 2100.32, null, 'DESPESA', 5, 4);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Instrumentos', '2017-06-10', null, 1040.32, null, 'DESPESA', 4, 3);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Café', '2017-04-10', '2017-04-10', 4.32, null, 'DESPESA', 4, 2);
INSERT INTO lancamento (descricao, data_vencimento, data_pagamento, valor, observacao, tipo, codigo_categoria, codigo_pessoa) values ('Lanche', '2017-06-10', null, 10.20, null, 'DESPESA', 4, 1);
```

Minha classe criada

```
package com.example.algamoney.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lancamento")
public class Lancamento {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    
    private String descricao;
    
    @Column(name = "data_vencimento")
    private LocalDate dataVencimento;
    
    @Column(name = "data_pagamento")
    private LocalDate dataPagamento;
    
    private BigDecimal valor;
    
    private String observacao;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipoLancamento tipoLancamento;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_categoria")
    private Categoria categoria;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_pessoa")
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    
    

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataVencimento() {
        return dataVencimento;
    }

    public void setDataVencimento(LocalDate dataVencimento) {
        this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
    }

    public LocalDate getDataPagamento() {
        return dataPagamento;
    }

    public void setDataPagamento(LocalDate dataPagamento) {
        this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public TipoLancamento getTipoLancamento() {
        return tipoLancamento;
    }

    public void setTipoLancamento(TipoLancamento tipoLancamento) {
        this.tipoLancamento = tipoLancamento;
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }

    public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        this.pessoa = pessoa;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Lancamento other = (Lancamento) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cria as operacoes em arquivos separados, um para CREATE e outro arquivo para os INSERTs. Verifica se os nomes estao seguindo as convensoes. Lembrando que a numeracao do CREATE deve ser anterior a dos INSERTs.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#naming